# Validation Error after using date format jquery

Tags: jquery

When i remove date format from my code it works fine.But when i add date format ,then the checks of from date and to date dont work.i.e my validation logic fails for to date and from date.

A

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
            **dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',**             
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: 'images/calender.jpg',
            buttonText: "Calendar",
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
        });

        var dates = $('#from, #top').datepicker({  

                onSelect: function (selectedDate) {               
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate";                    
                dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, new Date(selectedDate));
            }
        });

    });

</script>


<label for="from">
    From</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="from" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<label for="to">
    To</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="to" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I see no validation happening here...

Comment: var dates = $('#from, #top').datepicker({  

                onSelect: function (selectedDate) {               
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate"                    
                dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, new Date(selectedDate));.................Its more like a business logic to date cant be less than from date and vica versa..